# Introduction images in android app

Tags: android

How to make activity which shows introduction images when android app is launched for the first time?

I have 4  images that describe the app. So I want those images to show up when the app runs for the first time and user can swipe from one image to the next in order to unblock working part of the app.

Comment: what you have tried? did you go through the `viewpager`

Answer (score 2):

For checking if app is lunched first time use SharedPreferences and for displaying images you have to use Bitmap, because without it you will get memory errors.

Add this code in your activity class.(Not in onCreate method)

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

After in your onCreate method check if app lunched first time and add images to imageView widget.

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

    if (isFirstRun) {

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image1,350,350));
    imageView2.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image2,350,350));

        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a flag in sharedPreferences the first time you access the tutorial, then check it on launch.

```
If no flag: 
LauncherActivity -> TutorialActivity (shows four images) save flag -> MainActivity

If flagged:
Launcher Activity -> MainActivity
```

Check android dev guide for sharepreferences help.

Also Im not sure what you mean about showing during installation. If you mean during loading, then just go ahead and display the images during loading?

Answer (score 0):

This is called Appintro. Which runs first time when app launches

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public boolean isFirstStart;
    Context mcontext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //  Intro App Initialize SharedPreferences
                SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

                //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true
                isFirstStart = getSharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

                //  Check either activity or app is open very first time or not and do action
                if (isFirstStart) {

                    //  Launch application introduction screen
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyIntro.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor e = getSharedPreferences.edit();
                    e.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
                    e.apply();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }
}
```

http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/10/android-appintro-slider-example.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro

[image]